# revit python macros vs scripts

Tags: python, revit

Why does the following code work as a script inRevitPython Shell but throw errors as a Macro when added to a Module?  the idea is to collect the doors, query their host object for fire rating and frame details, then asign them to the doors.

The error is "None type has no attribute set()".  So it must be the door elements throwing this error.  But still, why does the very same code (only modifying how doc is defined) perform as a script but not a macro?

```
def updateDoors(self):
    doc = self.Document
    doors = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory( BuiltInCategory.OST_Doors ).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()

    t = Transaction(doc, 'Door Update')
    t.Start()

    for d in doors:

        wallRating = "---"
        doorRating = "---"
        doorNumber = "---"
        wallFr = "---"
        wallH = "---"
        wallJ = "---"

        if d.Host is not None and d is not None:

            wallTypeId = d.Host.GetTypeId() 
            wall = doc.GetElement(wallTypeId)
            if wall.LookupParameter('Fire Rating') is not None:
                wallFr = wall.LookupParameter('Fire Rating').AsString()
            # Get Door Jamb from the wall
            if wall.LookupParameter('Frame Jamb') is not None:
                wallJ = wall.LookupParameter('Frame Jamb').AsString()
            # Get Door Head from the wall
            if wall.LookupParameter('Frame Head') is not None:
                wallH = wall.LookupParameter('Frame Head').AsString()

            if str(wallFr) == '':
                d.LookupParameter('Fire Rating-Instance').Set('--')
            if str(wallFr) == '0':
                d.LookupParameter('Fire Rating-Instance').Set('--')
            if str(wallFr) == '1':
                d.LookupParameter('Fire Rating-Instance').Set('45')
            if str(wallFr) == '2':
                d.LookupParameter('Fire Rating-Instance').Set('90')
            if str(wallFr) == '3':
                d.LookupParameter('Fire Rating-Instance').Set('120')

            if d.LookupParameter('Over ride wall assigned details').AsValueString() == 'No':    
                d.LookupParameter('Jamb').Set(wallJ)
                d.LookupParameter('Head').Set(wallH)

    t.Commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it in the SharpDevelop debugger and you will see for yourself which line of code causes the problem. That will enable you to see the values of all the variables, and you can examine which of them is None.

Furthermore, this line is very weird:

`wall = doc.GetElement(wallTypeId)`

It is assigning the wall **type** to the variable wall.

All parameter values are being read from the wall **type**, not the wall instance.

Is that your intention?

If so, I recommend renaming the `wall` variable to `wallType` to avoid confusing yourself and others.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Yes, the intent is to collect "type" parameters from the wall family and assign them to "instance" parameters of the doors.  My debugger throws an error when run, so I rebooted my machine.  Now the script works... debugging 101?

Comment: Everything works nicely now with the exception of setting the 'jamb' and 'head' parameters.  the error is "Multiple Targets Could match".  Leads me to believe there are multiple parameters of the door families or instances named 'head' and 'jamb' - although scouring through the elements, i don't find that to be the case.  I am struggling to get the debugger to run without crashing.  Ill need to look into this.

Comment: congratulations on moving forward. yes, when you select parameters by display name (not recommended!), you can get multiple values for the same name. read more on that and how to cope with it here: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/06/cnc-direct-export-wall-parts-to-dxf-and-sat.html#2015.2